# How to have a right aligned list in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a nested list which I want to be aligned to the right side of the head. Here's an example of a regular list:
[image]

And here's an example of the list I'm trying to get:

[image]

Notice that the list items are aligned to the right of the head. I tried using the "em" unit on the nested list to move the entire thing left, but that didn't work because of the varying head lengths. IE one head was named "Head" while another was "Super Long Head" so the amount of shifting needed was different. I'm trying to avoid having to style each nested list individually.

So how would I align the nested list to the right of the head?

Comment: Cover the Head in a tag and give `direction="rtl"` for the tag.

Comment: why wouldnt `head{text-align: right;}` work? (not real css but considering you provided giant pictures instead of code i figured it would make the most sense)

Comment: What is your markup exactly, and what specific CSS did you try? And why do you say “nested list”? I see no nesting here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code it works fine.

```
<ul>
    <label dir="rtl">Head</label>
    <li>Jaw</li>
    <li>Kaiwn</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may need to do is this:

```
    ul{margin:0; padding:0;}
    Ul li{margin-left:-10px;}
```

or you could try:

```
    ul{margin:0 0 0 20px; padding:0;}
    ul li{margin:0;}
```